# Unable to update pricing for plan in sandbox account (PRICING_SCHEME_UPDATE_NOT_ALLOWED) in paypal API

Tags: paypal-sandbox

Unable to update pricing for plan in sandbox account (PRICING_SCHEME_UPDATE_NOT_ALLOWED)

**Request:-**
https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans/P-5TD04514DU568400GMDCGH2I/update-pricing-schemes

```
{
"pricing_schemes": [{
"billing_cycle_sequence": 2,
"pricing_scheme": {
"fixed_price": {
"value": "50",
"currency_code": "USD"
}
}
}
]
}
```

**Response:-**

```
{
"name": "UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY",
"message": "The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.",
"debug_id": "1f4c7375963cb",
"details": [
{
"issue": "PRICING_SCHEME_UPDATE_NOT_ALLOWED",
"description": "Pricing scheme update is not allowed for the plan."
}
],
"links": [
{
"href": "#",
"rel": "information_link",
"method": "GET"
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, updating the plan's pricing scheme is not allowed. It is not listed as one of the patchable fields.

If you need a new pricing scheme, create a new plan.